# Cannot convert std::reference<T> to std::reference<const T> on Clang

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, clang, std

I would expect that std::reference_wrapper would work as a reference in terms of converting non-const into const, like:

```
int a = 10;
int& refA = a;
const int& constRefA = refA;
```

The following code compiles and works fine in MSVC and GCC, but not on Clang. I just don't understand why, is it UB, or actually an issue on Clang compiler?

```
#include <functional>
#include <optional>

int main()
{
    int a = 10;

    std::reference_wrapper<int> ref = a;
    std::reference_wrapper<const int> constRef = ref;

    std::optional<std::reference_wrapper<int>> optRef = a;
    std::optional<std::reference_wrapper<const int>> optConstRef = optRef;

    return 0;
}
```

On Clang only, displays the following error:

```
prog.cc:13:39: error: no viable conversion from 'reference_wrapper<int>' to 'reference_wrapper<const int>'
std::reference_wrapper<const int> constRef = ref;
```

https://wandbox.org/permlink/FSY4tCvE9B17hbVn

> ```
> prog.cc:13:39: error: no viable conversion from 'reference_wrapper<int>' to 'reference_wrapper<const int>'
>     std::reference_wrapper<const int> constRef = ref;
>                                       ^          ~~~
> /opt/wandbox/clang-head/include/c++/v1/__functional_base:374:28: note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: no known conversion from 'std::reference_wrapper<int>' to 'const std::reference_wrapper<const int> &' for 1st argument
> class _LIBCPP_TEMPLATE_VIS reference_wrapper
>                            ^
> /opt/wandbox/clang-head/include/c++/v1/__functional_base:374:28: note: candidate constructor (the implicit move constructor) not viable: no known conversion from 'std::reference_wrapper<int>' to 'std::reference_wrapper<const int> &&' for 1st argument
> /opt/wandbox/clang-head/include/c++/v1/__functional_base:386:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'std::reference_wrapper<int>' to 'std::reference_wrapper<const int>::type &' (aka 'const int &') for 1st argument
>     reference_wrapper(type& __f) _NOEXCEPT
>     ^
> /opt/wandbox/clang-head/include/c++/v1/__functional_base:389:14: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'std::reference_wrapper<int>' to 'std::reference_wrapper<const int>::type &&' (aka 'const int &&') for 1st argument
>     private: reference_wrapper(type&&); public: // = delete; // do not bind to temps
>              ^
> /opt/wandbox/clang-head/include/c++/v1/__functional_base:394:5: note: candidate function
>     operator type&() const _NOEXCEPT {return *__f_;}
>     ^
> prog.cc:16:54: error: no viable conversion from 'optional<reference_wrapper<int>>' to 'optional<reference_wrapper<const int>>'
>     std::optional<std::reference_wrapper<const int>> optConstRef = optRef;
>                                                      ^             ~~~~~~
> /opt/wandbox/clang-head/include/c++/v1/optional:689:41: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'std::optional<std::reference_wrapper<int>>' to 'const std::optional<std::reference_wrapper<const int>> &' for 1st argument
>     _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY constexpr optional(const optional&) = default;
>                                         ^
> /opt/wandbox/clang-head/include/c++/v1/optional:690:41: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'std::optional<std::reference_wrapper<int>>' to 'std::optional<std::reference_wrapper<const int>> &&' for 1st argument
>     _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY constexpr optional(optional&&) = default;
>                                         ^
> /opt/wandbox/clang-head/include/c++/v1/optional:691:41: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'std::optional<std::reference_wrapper<int>>' to 'std::nullopt_t' for 1st argument
>     _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY constexpr optional(nullopt_t) noexcept {}
>                                         ^
> /opt/wandbox/clang-head/include/c++/v1/optional:715:15: note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with _Up = std::optional<std::reference_wrapper<int>> &]: no member named '_EnableIfImpl' in 'std::_MetaBase<false>'
>     constexpr optional(_Up&& __v)
>               ^
> /opt/wandbox/clang-head/include/c++/v1/optional:730:5: note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with _Up = std::reference_wrapper<int>]: no member named '_EnableIfImpl' in 'std::_MetaBase<false>'
>     optional(const optional<_Up>& __v)
>     ^
> /opt/wandbox/clang-head/include/c++/v1/optional:748:5: note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with _Up = std::reference_wrapper<int>]: no member named '_EnableIfImpl' in 'std::_MetaBase<false>'
>     optional(optional<_Up>&& __v)
>     ^
> /opt/wandbox/clang-head/include/c++/v1/optional:701:24: note: explicit constructor is not a candidate
>     constexpr explicit optional(_InPlaceT, _Args&&... __args)
>                        ^
> /opt/wandbox/clang-head/include/c++/v1/optional:722:24: note: explicit constructor is not a candidate
>     constexpr explicit optional(_Up&& __v)
>                        ^
> /opt/wandbox/clang-head/include/c++/v1/optional:738:14: note: explicit constructor is not a candidate
>     explicit optional(const optional<_Up>& __v)
>              ^
> /opt/wandbox/clang-head/include/c++/v1/optional:756:14: note: explicit constructor is not a candidate
>     explicit optional(optional<_Up>&& __v)
>              ^
> 2 errors generated.
> ```

Comment: [Can't reproduce](https://godbolt.org/z/bef9xr) in clang 9 and upwards.

Comment: Thanks @TedLyngmo You are right, on compiler explorer x64 it works properly. However ARMV7 version clang is showing the same error.
I don't know why it wouldn't work on wandbox either, since its the same compiler

Comment: Yes, it's strange that it doesn't work in wandbox when using the same versions that is working on godbolt. If I compile it locally on my computer using clang 10.0.1, it also works.

Answer (score 0):

The std library you are using on wandbox has a bug.  It only found 2 constructors and a conversion operator.

Compilers and standard libraries are not always in sync.

```
printf("Hello World");
int a = 10;

std::reference_wrapper<int> ref = a;
std::reference_wrapper<const int> constRef( ref );

std::optional<std::reference_wrapper<int>> optRef = a;
std::optional<std::reference_wrapper<const int>> optConstRef( optRef );

return 0;
```

By making the conversions explicit it works.  I don't know why; there aren't any explicit conversions differences in my reading of `reference_wrapper` construction and conversion operators.

But the lack of implicit reference wrapping conversion would explain why the optional would want it.

In any case, this is clearly a bug.  The universal conversion constructor for `reference_wrapper<const int>` should apply if:

```
 void FUN(int const&) {}
 FUN(ref)
```

overload resolution works, and it does for a `reference_wrapper<int>`.

Comment: This is something that is also happening in my CI system. Linux version is not compiling. Can it be that the stdlib is outdated?